# How to split a list accordions into two columns using css and react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I need to show a list of Accordions in two columns.
Each Accordion includes Summary and Details. Details are  visible only when summary is clicked.
I am not including this logic to keep this short.

Here is the react code.

```
<div class="container">
  {accordions.map(acc => (
    <div class="accordion">
      <AccordionSummary text={acc.summary} />
      <AccordionDetails text={acc.details} />
    </div>
  ))}
```

CSS here

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}
```

The problem with this approach is, when an accordion is clicked in one column, the other column will expand too ( as they are in the same row ).

If we can have two columns each with the display as grid, the problem will be solved. But distributing accordions into two columns is a problem on its own.

Can anyone suggest how to do this without expanding another column with same react code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are having the same map function to iterate through the acc object hence for the on click method, both the details and summary for one acc object are considered as a single entity. So i don't think it would be possible to achieve the thing you want with the same react code.

Comment: Its not a problem with onClick method. The functionality is working fine. Each accordion has a unique id. Grid places then on the same row. When one row expands, the other expands too but with empty block ( details are not show for other accordion).

Comment: Have u tried logging the acc.details? Because the code is fine then. I guess there might be a typo in the  AccordionDetails.js file

Comment: Functionality is fine. No issues there. Its CSS grid issue.  There are two accordions on one row. If one expands, the height of the column expands. So it impacts the entire row which I dont want. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would be better if u can show me the code if that's not an issue. I do understand your question

Comment: @HarikiranChalla Did you manage to find a solution to this?